# Common Session for application and web browser

Tags: iphone, wordpress, web-services, session, session-variables

I have a query regarding to session maintain between application and web browser.

I'm developing an iPhone application and there is also one website (in wordpress) same for this application.

My question is , is it possible to show user login in mobile's web browser if he/she is login into application from same mobile device?

In short, I want to know where is this session stored? In application or in device? If it is in device then how can I check same for the web browser?

Answer (score 5):

Cookies are stored per app, **not per device**. Safari has its own sandbox whereas each native app runs in its own sandbox, otherwise Safari's security model would be compromised.

> In OS X, cookie storage is shared across all apps; **in iOS, cookie storage is per-app**. 
> Reference: [About the URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).

So for your scenario, this is how you should be able to make it work (I haven't tried it though):

1. In your mobile app, open website in Safari. Send a HTTP header to tell the web server that this hit is coming in from your native app
2. If you are already logged in via Safari, then your server will identify the user. Code your server to send back a redirect response (only in case when the request is from native app). This redirect response will contain a session cookie / auth_token with it. Also, the redirect location would use the iOS custom url scheme, e.g. `myapp://mydashboard`
3. In your native app, [register the app as the handler of that custom url](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18) so that it can catch and handle the redirect appropriately
4. In subsequent requests from the native app, send the session cookie / auth_token

Hope it helps.

Comment: i think it is not sufficient that users have to dependent on browser...like it will only work with safari... is there any other way..?

Comment: Maybe I was unable to convey the solution properly. Safari will be the common communication mechanism between mobile web and native app. Other than that you would not be able to share auth details. Once auth is confirmed then user should be able to continue using the web resources either in Safari or native app itself. Sarafi will not be required for each resource request after initial auth checking.